# Find the word at $48$ position?

Tags: permutations

> The letters in the word "PLACES" are permuted in all possible ways and arranged in the alphabetical order.Find the word at 48 position.

a)AESPCL

b)ALCEPS

c)ALSCEP

d)AESPLC

**MyApproach**

As per dictionary I started with

AC--->$4$!=$24$

AE--->$4$!=$24$

So,I think the word start with AE but I am confused which to choose.

> Am I right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The approach is correct.
As there will be 24 words starting with AE, the 48th will be the last one starting with AE i.e. AE-S-P-L-C.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

First, use the [Factorial Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) in order to calculate $47_6$ as follows:

- $47/5!=5!\cdot\color\red0+47$
- $47/4!=4!\cdot\color\red1+23$
- $23/3!=3!\cdot\color\red3+ 5$
- $ 5/2!=2!\cdot\color\red2+ 1$
- $ 1/1!=1!\cdot\color\red1+ 0$
- $ 0/0!=0!\cdot\color\red0+ 0$

Then, take the resulting string of $\color\red{013210}$, and run the following algorithm:

- $\color\red013210,\color\red{A}CELPS$
- $\color\red13210,C\color\red{E}LPS$
- $\color\red3210,CLP\color\red{S}$
- $\color\red210,CL\color\red{P}$
- $\color\red10,C\color\red{L}$
- $\color\red0,\color\red{C}$

The result is $\color\red{AESPLC}$.

Answer (score 0):

AESP is fixed as you have 2 options you got by finding rank . IN DICTIONARY  AESPCL will be 47 th word while AESPLC will be 48 th as alphabetically L comes after C . Hence option D.

Answer (score 0):

word is  "PLACES"

Arrange this in alphabetical order like ACELPS

fixing AC---- we had remaining 4 letters we can arrange them in 4! ways

1st word is AC (ELPS)

4! ways means (4*3*2*1=24) In 24 ways we can arrange those 4 letters(ELPS)

To get 24th word just revers the remaining  4 letters
like  AC ELPS  as  AC SPLE

we had 24th word  as ACSPLE

But we need 48th word  so again fix AE---- Remaining 4 letters in 4! ways

To get 48th word just revers the remaining  4 letters
like  AE CLPS  as  AE SPLC

Therefore  48th word  is AESPLC